# blender texture paint problem: color combining with texture during stencil painting

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

i was just texture painting using stencil and it was working fine, i dont know what i pressed or what happened but colour is mixing with the image and i cannot turn it off, if i turn color to red or whatever, that color strokes will i get, i just want to project image onto my model like it was just working before. [image: the image shows that colour is affecting image texture]

Comment: hello maybe pack your image and share your file so that we can try: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: What is your blend mode for your brush set to? If it is Mix, it should behave as 'Normal' in Photoshop. If it is not, that might explain why it looks like it is set to 'Screen' here in your paint result. Also, is the mix mode for combining textures in play here, like are you painting onto a new image above the previous one?

Comment: i solved it, i had accidentally painted some strokes of another texture so now the result i was getting was combination of two, i used the symmetry to solve it as left side of my model was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it, i had accidentally painted some strokes of another texture so now the result i was getting was combination of two, i used the symmetry to solve it as left side of my model was fine